# UITableView scrollView delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have a tableview set inside a UIViewController

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

with delegates set in viewDidLoad

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

The following methods never get called:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Isn't tableviewdelegate supposed to conform to uiscrollviewdelegate as well?
Any idea why these methods are never called?

Comment: Does the tableView work in other respects?  Are other (tableView) delegate methods (such as `didSelectRowAtIndex`) working?

Comment: Yes the other delegate methods such as didSelectRowAtIndex are working

Comment: Actually selection is not working on the tableview..but the datasource is correctly displayed

Comment: Have you tried setting the dataSource and delegate in ViewWillAppear, rather than ViewDidLoad?

Comment: self.tableView.scrollView.delegate = self; try this

Comment: @Bejibun That's won't work. `UITableView` doesn't have a `scrollView` property. It is (extends) `UIScrollView`.

Comment: try the linking from IB. BTW, for IBOutlet component, weak reference is good enough.

Comment: try to cast your tableView to (UIScrollView*) and then assign delegate to self.

Comment: There's no reason, given the code you show that the delegate methods shouldn't have been called. There's no need to move the code to viewDidAppear, or awakeFromNib, or to cast the table view to UIScrollView. The fact that your selection isn't working suggests that the delegate isn't set. Is self.tableView non-nil? Did you set the data source in IB possibly? Are you sure that your delegate methods are spelled correctly?

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things:

1) Set the UITableView's delegate property, as was suggested by others.

AND

2) Add conformance to the UITableViewDelegate protocol.

If you do just the first step, the UIScrollViewDelegate methods will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Add the delegate lines in `awakeFromNib` instead of `viewDidLoad`. I had the same problem and that worked.